# boost::shared_ptr destroy callback

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I was digging through documentation of boost, looking for callback which is called just before object in boost::shared_ptr is being deleted, so i can write object state back to hard drive, and remove weak_ptr element from std::map.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a deleter function to shared ptr and write object state in this function.

```
template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr(Y * p, D d);
```

Answer (score 4):

When the shared pointer is deleted it should call your objects destructor. You can write your object to the disk at that time, right there in its destructor.